# Matlab - selecting complex values from array

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

Consider an array, A, which contains complex numbers.

When I print the absolute values of this array I get graph that resembles a range of peaks. I am interested in creating a new array with only those numbers that correspond to the peaks.

If I use `pks = findpeaks(abs(A))` I am returned with a new array `pks` of real numbers.

However, I want an array that contains the complex number so I can work with the real and imaginary values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second output of `findpeaks`

```
[~,loc] = findpeaks(abs(A));
```

Then the complex values will just be `A(loc)`;

Comment: @William Thanks ;) Consider accepting the answer as valid!